# emulate dual monitor using a second machine

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have monitors of my two machines side by side and I use them both with a single keyboard/mouse using Synergy+ (now hosted at Google Code) which works great.

But is it possible to use the monitor of my secondary machine as the secondary monitor of my primary? I am on XP so from what I understand I cannot just rdc from secondary to this primary. In any case that would be a different session altogether and I would prefer to be able to extend my desktop over the two monitors.

Any solutions or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Google Synergy+"? I think you mean just "Synergy+".

Comment: @Ignacio: wrong choice of words. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/)

I don't know any free solutions unfortunately. I wanted to do something similar myself and settled on MaxiVista after I couldn't find any alternative (short of modifying Synergy myself, which I didn't have the patience for).

Comment: Thanks Matthew. MaxiVista looks good. Do you know of any free solutions? Is there a way to move this question to SuperUser?

Comment: High reputation users do that - voted to close (move to superuser) ;)

Comment: @Hemal: I don't know any free solutions unfortunately. I wanted to do something similar myself and settled on MaxiVista after I couldn't find any alternative (short of modifying Synergy myself, which I didn't have the patience for).